# Movie or show about some space/alien dust that causes animals to explode

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

I remember watching a movie or a show as a kid where this dust from space or from aliens fell onto a mouse, and it made the mouse violent and go after a cat. After a time, the mouse exploded into this glowing slime/goo and onto the cat, infecting the cat and causing it to attack a dog. It continued to escalate until the dog exploded on this woman and her child.

I don't remember the year, but it was released sometime in the 80s or early 90s.